# Vagrant synced_folder id option

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

The syntax for enabling an NFS folder share in Vagrant is commonly posted as:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "<HOST_DIR>", "<VM_DIR>", id: "???", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["nolock", "vers=3", "udp"]
```

Note the `id` argument. I've read the Vagrant docs at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html, but this option isn't mentioned.

Given its frequent use in Vagrantfiles, I assume this option is relevant, if not mandatory. What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 1):

When using the default VirtualBox shared folder mechanism, the `id` option will be what appears when you list your mount points in the guest OS using `mount`. For example:

**Vagrantfile**

```
config.vm.synced_folder "<HOST_DIR>", "/opt/bar", id: "foo"
```

**Guest OS via SSH**

```
$ mount
...
foo on /opt/bar type vboxsf (uid=1000,gid=1000,rw)
```

I have not tested whether the `id` option is used for `nfs` synced folders, but I can confirm that it has no bearing on `rsync` synced folders.